# What limitations have GIMP scripts?

Tags: scripting, gimp

Photoshop scripts have serious limitations - for example it is impossible or hard to paint using them. Do GIMP scripts also have limitations or we can do programmatically all the same that we can by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Basic Scheme page](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Scheme/) states:

> One of the wonderful features of GIMP is that it all its functionality may be accessed through scripting.
>   ...
>   All functionality of GIMP is available through the procedural database (PDB). Each procedural database function has a corresponding Scheme function mapping.